# Key-presses happening multiple times during OpenBSD installation

Tags: system-installation, openbsd, chrome-book

I am trying to install OpenBSD on HP Chromebook 11 G4 with CoreBoot (UEFI) installed through MrChromeBox firmware-util script.

During the initial boot prompt (when you see the `boot>`) I can easily type anything there (like entering into User Kernel Config with `boot -c` for example).

But after loading the installation program each time I press any key, and I mean literally any key including power button or enter, I need to wait for 1-2 seconds before chromebook responds.
What is even worse is that each key-press is recorded/recognized multiple times.

I have already found that setting `kern.timecounter.hardware=acpihpet0` using `sysctl` can help but unfortunately I can't get past installation (typing "done" is not an option and it is required in some places because of failed load of initial iwm0 firmware)

I know it might be the tip of an iceberg but I would like to begin with fixing the key-presses issue during an installation process.

Since this suppose to be a question there should be at least one question mark.
Is there any way to set `kern.timecounter.hardware=acpihpet0` from UKC or any other way to fix each key being pressed multiple times during installation ?

As a side note: from I can see most things during boot are not configured (like `acpicpu at acpi0 not configured` or `Intel Bay Trail LPC .... not configured`.

Oh and I have already tried using an external keyboard with no luck since it does not work during installation program for some reason.

Update:

Just to preempt question since I did not mention this in the original question.

The installation program does not detect any disk except for the build-in emmc.
If it was not for this I could simply install the OpenBSD with autoinstall (multiple "a" count as 1 in that particular prompt and naming the response file like "bbbbb" works).

Because of the above and the fact there is only wireless connection build-in I can't get sets necessary to finish the installation. I've managed to get past disk layout stage but there is nowhere I can get the sets from since the installation medium is also unavailable.

Update 2:

I have managed to install OpenBSD via Linux MX live usb with virtualbox installed.

Sadly the keyboard is still not working. Any external usb device is not recognized either.

When I press the power button I can see there is an info with something like:

```
pckbc timeout
```

I will keep this question updated.

Answer (score 5):

You can try disabling `acpihpet` at the UKC:

```
UKC> disable acpihpet
```

It might be helpful to post a message to the `misc@openbsd.org` mailing list, so that the devs can help you out.  If at all possible, include the full output of `dmesg`, but I understand it might be hard with a non-functioning keyboard.  If you have another machine (with the same architecture, of course) around, you might try using that to install OpenBSD onto a USB stick and then use it to boot the Chromebook.  That way you'd be booting a full kernel, which might correctly support the internal keyboard (and in all likelihood the external one too).  It would then be easy to get the `dmesg`.

The way that the keyboard is attached might be relevant (old AT-style via `pckbd`, USB using `uhid`, I2C using `ikbd`, etc), and the full `dmesg` will also show/hint at why the USB keyboard isn't detected with the installation's kernel (which has support for a more limited set of hardware than the full one).

**Update:**

About the external drive: if you *have* to boot in UEFI mode on the Chromebook, then you'll need to make a UEFI installation on the external disk as well, instead of a Master Boot Record setup.  To avoid reinstalling OpenBSD, see if you have something like a "legacy boot" option on the Chromebook's BIOS, and try to boot from the external disk.  Otherwise, try to make an UEFI installation to the disk, using the spare machine.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions but unfortunately none of them solved the issue.
I have tried disabling acpihpet but it did not do anything as far as I see.
Installing OpenBSd on an external drive have not working because I get kernel panic with the message `root device not found`. I guess this might be because I am making the installation on a different (but similar) device. Anyway, thank you again for the suggestions.

Comment: About the update: for this machine it makes no difference whether I use legacy seabios or UEFI. I have checked it multiple times. With seabios keyboard "repeats itself" just like in UEFI. 
And I have made sure the installation on an external disk was done in UEFI mode, still without luck.